# Mongo Spark connector, auth error

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to connect to my local MongoDB from Spark.
I've read few topics about it, but none of them works. What is wrong with my setup ?

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName.collectionName")
    .getOrCreate()

  it should "connect" in {
    val rdd = MongoSpark.load(spark)
    println(rdd.count())
  }
```

**Auth setup :**

```
mongo dbName --eval "db.createUser({ user: 'user', pwd: 'pass', roles: [ { role: '-dbOwner', db: 'dbName' } ] });"
```

**Error :**

```
14:13:04.538 [ScalaTest-run-running-MongoConnector] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
14:13:04.540 [ScalaTest-run-running-MongoConnector] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
14:13:04.563 [cluster-ClusterId{value='59f5d3e0ee179e015809a115', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
14:13:04.564 [cluster-ClusterId{value='59f5d3e0ee179e015809a115', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='user', source='dbName', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
(...)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:117)
14:17:28.944 [cluster-ClusterId{value='59f5d4e8ee179e027923cfdf', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='user', source='dbName', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }}}]
14:17:29.451 [cluster-ClusterId{value='59f5d4e8ee179e027923cfdf', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:2}
```

**Versions:**
1. Spark 2.2.0
2. Mongo 3.4
3. Mongo-spark-connector_2.11, version: 2.2.0
4. Scala 2.11.8

**EDIT:**
I;ve tried to add to

```
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName.collectionName")
```

flags:

- ?authSource=admin
- ?authSource=dbOwner
- ?authSource=dbName
- ?authenticationDatabase=dbName

but none of them works

Comment: Are you able to connect via mongo shell with that auth ? The reason I asked is because there your role entry is suspicious `-dbOwner` that would create an error. I suggest to follow [Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) tutorial to create the correct auth

Comment: Yes, I can login from shell as that user. I've even added admin user :
`mongo database --eval "db.createUser({ user: 'admin', pwd: 'admin', roles: [ { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' } ] });"`, and in conntector : `"spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/database.collection?authSource=admin`. And still fails

Comment: Note that `userAdminAnyDatabase` is for user administration, unless explicitly configured, the role is only limited to user administrations.

Comment: Did you find a solution??

Comment: Posted what I found

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and after a while got this setup working with `authSource`.

First, make sure your mongo setup is correct (if you only have one machine, skip this step), if you have a replica set, make sure the communication between them is OK via logs.

In my setup I have an `admin` user on `admin` database and custom user on custom database, from which I want to read. The only permission this custom user has is `dbOwner`. The command I'm using in spark is:

```
df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql")
  .options(uri="mongodb://CUSTOM_USERNAME:PASSWORD@ip.address:27017/?authSource=CUSTOM_DB_NAME", database="CUSTOM_DB_NAME", collection="COLLECTION_NAME")
  .load()
```

and it works perfect for me. Some things to note:

- Default value of `authSource` is admin, so if you can't connect at all, make an admin user on `admin` database with permissions `{role:'root',db:'admin'}`. Then default config should be good enough.
- Note that slash before questionmark in the URI - otherwise URI is invalid.
- My mongo connector version is 2.4.0 - maybe this was broken before.

Best of luck to you!

More docs:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-48
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource